# What could be causing Wordpress to create user accounts for members?

Tags: wordpress, civimember

We are running CiviCRM 5.13.4 on the lastest version of Wordpress.  We have just moved over to Wordpress, so by rights there shouldn't be many Wordpress users registered.

We have CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync installed.  We have two types of membership - Full, and Associate. Wordpress Member Sync is setup to change the role on any matching user to either 'Full Member' or 'Associate Member'.

It is **not** set to "Create WordPress Users - Create a WordPress User for each Membership when one does not already exist."

However, bit by bit the number of users in our Wordpress system is climbing - and it's only members who are having accounts mysteriously auto-created. Yesterday there were 180 members with user accounts, today 227.

We can't think of anything we're doing that would trigger these accounts to be created, and as every account has some sort of membership attached to it we can only think that the culprit is something buggy in CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync, but could it be anything else?

Comment: The plugin will create WordPress users for Contacts with memberships (lapsed or current) when cron runs, so that may account for the new users. It's not a bug, however, it's a feature :-) Could you expand on your Member Sync setup and why you *wouldn't* want Users mapped to Contacts?

Comment: Hi, thanks @ChristianWach that clears up the cause.  

We do want users mapped to contacts, but as it's a new site we ideally wanted people to re-register themselves so that they could choose their own usernames and passwords.  As it stands this way they'll have to do a password reset, and as we're on Wordpress Multisite they can't change their username (eg mr-robin-cantrill-fenwick)

Comment: You can customise how you want to build the username. Please refer to https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-wp-member-sync/issues/27

Comment: If people need to re-register, then you may want to consider resetting their membership data or customising the notification email to explicitly suggest a password reset.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianWach - We decided in the end to sync and create a wordpress user for each match, so everyone had a pre-existing account, and then we advised all users that they needed to conduct a password reset.  We have removed references to logging in by username, and advised everyone to login with their email address

Comment: Good call Robin.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in comments above